# How to move multiple objects under a collection using script?

Tags: python, collections

Things like this
[image]

This 3 objects combine one collection and I want to move this collection to a specific point.
This require objects keep relationship between them and set the center of collection to a new coordinate, use script.

Comment: The typical approach is to parent each of the objects to the same empty, maintaining the original transforms, and then to move the empty if you want to move the whole group.

Comment: Thanks I am trying that, but I don't know how to active a collection and add an empty to it. I have several collections need to do this but empty_add() always add object to actived collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding an empty to the collection, parenting each object in the collection to it, and then move the empty by changing its transforms.  Here's how to add an empty and parent objects in a collection to it:

```py
import bpy

# replace the next line with code to select a collection
col = bpy.data.collections['Collection']

# Add an empty to the collection:
empty = bpy.data.objects.new('empty', None)
col.objects.link(empty)

# Make the empty parent to other objects in the collection:
for obj in col.objects:
    if not obj is empty:
        obj.parent = empty
```

For most object types you have to first create the low level thing, like a mesh or a camera, then create the object using the low level thing. But for an empty there is no low level thing, so you use `None`.

Add an item to a collection by linking it to the collections `objects` member.

Set the parent in the obvious way, but don't parent the empty to itself.

You can also change parameters of the empty, for instance:

```
empty.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
```

Now you can move everything by changing `empty.location` for instance:

```
empty.location = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is very exhaustive.